# How to use matlab to send email through Outlook and with some excel tables shown in the body of email

Tags: excel, matlab, email, outlook

I want to use matlab to automatically send the email (through outlook) to others while I want the table is to be shown in the body of email, not as the attachment.

Suppose i have a spreadsheet named ABC.xlsx, if I want to extract one sheet and put it in the body of email, what should I do?

I use the following code,

```
h = actxserver('outlook.Application');
mail = h.CreateItem('olMail');
mail.Subject = 'test';
mail.To = ['***@****.com'];

mail.BodyFormat = 'olFormatHTML';
mail.HTMLBody = 'This is a test for email sending!';



mail.attachments.Add('ABC.xlsx');


mail.Send;
h.release;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at function `xlsread`, documented [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). After reading the desired contents of the xlsx page, you can format them as an html table and put it in `mail.HTMLBody`.